# wamp server :How to deploy jsp application

Tags: jsp, deployment, wampserver

I am newly started using WAMP server. I am unable to deploy my java application on it.
only Html pages run. Please help with directory structure and where to keep jsp, java, .class ,war,xml files. JSP code is shown on html page when i click link for jsp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WAMP Server is primarily meant for PHP/MySQL Development on Windows and does not support Java/JSP out of the box.(AFAIK) While it would be possible to use the same WAMP installation for configuring it to support JSPs, you would still need a Servlet Container for interpreting your Java/JSP source files. Since you are new to WAMP, it would be more logical to install a different Servlet Container such as Tomcat given below to reduce the time needed to get you up and running.

To deploy JSP applications with minimal configuration/maintenance other than your project specifications, check out Apache Tomcat for Windows.

http://tomcat.apache.org/ - [Download Tomcat 6.0(Windows Service)](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi)

Answer (score 9):

I will actually answer your question instead of being a snotty know-it-all.

Yes, you can deply wampserver and Tomcat at the same time on the same computer.  By default Wamp binds itself to port 80 which is the default port for the http protocol.  I believe Tomcat binds itself to port 8080 so there should be no conflict but if there is, just change Tomcat to 8080 and you can run them both at the same time.  If you want something small and easier to work with try Blazix.

Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong and/or I don't understand the question... But if you are using [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) : is that not a server for PHP development -- and not JAVA/JSP ?

If you need to deploy some JAVA-related application, you'll probably have to use a server that supports JAVA, I suppose -- what about something like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Wamp server and Tomcat both work on the same machine without any configuration error or any else error.
So just go on and install Tomcat for jsp files if you have installed Wamp for other web designing purposes.
I have myself done the same thing and it works continuously.